# Python - How to combine / concatenate / join pandas series variables ignoring the empty variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

With the help of .loc method, I am identifying the values in a column in a Panda data frame based on values in the another column of the same data frame.

The code snippet is given below for your reference :

```
var1 = output_df['Player'].loc[output_df['Team']=='India'].reset_index(drop=True)
var2 = output_df['Player'].loc[output_df['Team']=='Australia'].reset_index(drop=True)
var3 = output_df['Player'].loc[output_df['Team']=='Algeria'].reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Update**

**There may be 'n' number of teams in my data frame but I want the top players from selective teams only. That's why I manually enter the team names in the code. And I may require top performer, 2nd top performer and so on. So cannot fetch values from a column in data frame by using join statement.**

Now I would be having 3 variables of type "pandas.core.series.Series"

I already sorted this data frame in the order of descending based on another column called "Score"

And my requirement is to fetch the top scoring player from each team and create an output variable combining all the player names with a ','.

I tried with the below command to get the desired output :

```
Final = var1[0]+','+var2[0]+','+var3[0]
```

It is producing the expected output successfully but suppose if any of the variable is empty - For example consider my data frame does not have top scoring player from Algeria, var3 will be empty. Hence when I execute the previous command, it is getting ended up with "Out of bounds" error

Is there any way to execute the previous command or is there any similar kind of command that has to ignore the null variable but combine the remaining variables together with a separator in between ?

**Update**

The logic that i get here will be used for framing sentences from words based on their POS tags (noun, adjective, verb, so on). Var1 will be used for storing Nouns arranged in descending order based on some score. Var2 will be used for storing Adjectives arranged in same order as noun and so on...

*Finally while framing a string / sentence I would be using these variables to concatenate. Ex: top-performing-noun + top-performing-adjective + top-performing-verb. Second sentence will be formed by 2nd-top-performing-noun + 2nd-top-performing-adjective ..... Right now I do not have code snippet for the same. It is being framed from Team-Player code.*

Hope this update helps to understand the question more clearly**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with `apply` for remove `NaN`s by [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dropna.html):

```
var1 = pd.Series(list('abcd'))
var2 = pd.Series(list('rftyru'))
var3 = pd.Series(list('de'))

print (pd.concat([var1, var2, var3], axis=1))

     0  1    2
0    a  r    d
1    b  f    e
2    c  t  NaN
3    d  y  NaN
4  NaN  r  NaN
5  NaN  u  NaN

Final = (pd.concat([var1, var2, var3], axis=1)
          .apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x.dropna()), axis=1))
print (Final)

0    a, r, d
1    b, f, e
2       c, t
3       d, y
4          r
5          u
dtype: object
```

But better is use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and [`GroupBy.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html) for top e.g `2` players.

For filtering `Teams` use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
#a bit changed data from another solution
df = pd.DataFrame([['Tim', 'India', 100],
                   ['Bob', 'Australia', 50],
                   ['John', 'Algeria', 123],
                   ['Sarah', 'Algeria', 456],
                   ['Jane', 'Australia', 9]],
                         columns=["Player", "Team", "Score"])


df1 = df[df['Team'].isin(['Algeria','India','Australia'])]
df1 = df1.sort_values('Score', ascending=False).groupby('Team').head(2)
print (df1)
  Player       Team  Score
3  Sarah    Algeria    456
2   John    Algeria    123
0    Tim      India    100
1    Bob  Australia     50
4   Jane  Australia      9

df1 = (df.sort_values('Score', ascending=False)
        .groupby('Team')['Player']
        .apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x.head(2)))
        .reset_index())
print (df1)

        Team       Player
0    Algeria  Sarah, John
1  Australia    Bob, Jane
2      India          Tim
```

For second top use [`GroupBy.nth`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.nth.html):

```
df1 = df.sort_values('Score', ascending=False).groupby('Team', as_index=False).nth(1)
print (df1)
  Player       Team  Score
2   John    Algeria    123
4   Jane  Australia      9
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael. I know about sorting and grouping dataframes. But I don't want my output to be a data frame. It should be just a string variable. So instead of creating another dataframe and fetching the desired column values (in your example df1.Player), is there any other way to concat as I have tried but also by ignoring the empty variable without throwing an error ?

Comment: Hmmm, not sure if understand. If working in pandas the best is use pandas function and last export column(s) to string.

Comment: Yes @jezrael. You have understood right. My question was super simplified. The thing is as per your option I cannot filter out players from few teams which I don't want. It will just fetch top scoring player from each group. Initially I did this. But later my requirement was changed. So tried to concatenate using '+' symbol and it was throwing error for empty variables. So trying for a similar solution now

Comment: Maybe the best is add some data sample with desired output, because without data hard to answering and hard verifying code. So there is problem last convert DataFrame to list or string? Can you explain more desired output from my sample?

Comment: The thing is as per your first solution, it will select all the top players from each team. I got that. But my requirement is not to get all teams. Only from selective teams. That's why my code snippet shows you that I manually entered the Team's name that I want. Suppose there are around 10 teams. I just need the top players from 3 teams (India, Australia and Algeria). So I store them in three variables and then combining it. If any of the variable is empty, it is throwing error which I want to bypass / overcome

Comment: Updated the question for better clarity

Comment: But then better is filter first `df1 = df[df['Team'].isin(['Algeria','India','Australia'])]` and then groupby
`df1 = df1.sort_values('Score', ascending=False).groupby('Team').head(2)`

Comment: Correct . Did that before . But what if I want to get 2nd top performing player or 3rd top performing player like that. head(n) gives me first 'n' number of records right ?

Comment: Yes, exactly you are right. And if have top 4 and there is only 2 players, it return only 2 and no error. In my asnwer I want top 2, but it return only one indian, because only one player.

Comment: Agreed @jezrael. But what if you need to get only the 2nd top player from few teams. Head() will not work here. Tail() also may not work here if the total number of players in each team is more than 2. Any inputs on this ?

Comment: Updated the question further and mentioned about exact requirements too. Please have a look at it once

Comment: If need only second top use `df1 = df.sort_values('Score', ascending=False).groupby('Team', as_index=False).nth(1)` - check [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#taking-the-nth-row-of-each-group)

Comment: Thanks @jezrael but I am getting this error : AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'nth'. Please note that I am using Python 3.x

Comment: Oh yes. There was a typo . And that's working like a charm !!!!!!!. So better I follow the traditional data frame way instead of storing in variables and concatenating them. Will accept yours as the answer I was looking for. Please update this command in your answer so that it will be easy for others to have a look at it.

Comment: Glad can help! I add it to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing the filtering for each team, you can use the pandas `groupby` function to do this, with some pre-filtering.

Since you want all the 1st players in each team, and all the 2nd, etc. in separate lists, you can rank players in each team, then groupby the rank.

So, first calculate the team rank, then filter to the teams you are interested in first, then group and concatenate the names together.

```
import pandas as pd
output_df = pd.DataFrame([['Tim', 'India', 100],
                          ['Bob', 'Australia', 50],
                          ['John', 'Algeria', 123],
                          ['Sarah', 'Algeria', 456],
                          ['Jane', 'Australia', 9],
                          ['Humphrey', 'India', 200]],
                         columns=["Player", "Team", "Score"])

output_df['Team Rank'] = output_df.groupby("Team").rank(ascending=False)['Score'].astype(int)

interested_teams = output_df[output_df['Team'].isin(['India', 'Australia'])]

players_by_rank = interested_teams.groupby("Team Rank").apply(lambda x: ", ".join(x['Player']))

print(players_by_rank)
```

And get players by rank

```
Team Rank
1    Bob, Humphrey
2        Tim, Jane
```

You can get a specific rank by using `.loc`. So for the second ranked players, use

```
players_by_rank.loc[2]
```

Comment: Thanks @Ken Syme. But I need top players from selective teams only. Not from all teams. I have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: And your answer gives me the top player from each team. What if I want to fetch second top player from each group. This is just for my understanding. I tried to mention second or next in the place of first() but to no avail. Any idea about it as well ?

Comment: got it . I want top scoring players separately and second top scoring players separately . head(2) will give top two players right ?

Comment: Further edits to update with these requirements. Can you please update the question with these requirements, and any others? Perhaps give an overview of why you are trying to do this?

Comment: Updated the question further and mentioned about exact requirements too